# CSS: horizontal position a popup at desired location

Tags: javascript, css

I have this button, which when clicked displays a popup.

The popup is a `div` element with `display:none` to begin with. When the button is clicked, I set the `display:block` to show the popup.

The vertical location of the popup is just fine; right above the invoking button. However, I'm not able to position the downward arrow (speech bubble?) in the such a way that it appears over the centre of the invoking button.

1. Can this be done with CSS?
2. I'm ok with javascript solution too as long as I don't have to pull in a dependency.
3. I'm ok with altering the structure of the html. The constraint that I have is both the popup and the button have to be in the same container. The button could be positioned anywhere in this container.

Perhaps a little code will help:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me!">
    <div class="sf-su-response sf-popup-panel popup">
        Sorry, I don't know :(
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    background: tomato;
}

.sf-popup-panel {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
}

.sf-popup-panel.popup {
    top: auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: auto;
}

.sf-popup-panel.open {
    display: block;
}

.sf-popup-panel.popup.open:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    top: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.sf-popup-panel.open:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    top: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0px;
}

.sf-su-response {
    padding: 15px;    
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $(".sf-su-response").toggleClass("open");
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru5aX/

**EDIT:**
Judging from the answers so far, perhaps, my question is not very clear.

Basically the button could be positioned anywhere in the parent div. I cannot make assumptions about it's position at design time. So solutions which set a `right` or `left` to specific values at design time would not work for me.

Of course, what would work is if i could somehow specify this popup to be positioned relative to the button; but, I don't know how :(

**EDIT2**

This is what I'm getting:

[image: Result]

This is what I want:

[image: Desired]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a solution for what you are asking.

http://jsfiddle.net/moellerb/vmUuc/

**Explaination**
Your "container" has a set width of 300px.  Since this is the parent element to your popup, the popup positions itself relative to that container's space.  In order to track the button 's position without heavy javascript, I would wrap the button and popup in another wrap container (.btn-wrap).  Set it to the button size in order to keep the containment size to the desired area of the button.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="btn-wrap"><!-- add another wrap around your button/popup -->
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me!"/>
        <div class="sf-su-response sf-popup-panel popup">
          Sorry, I don't know :(
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

Made a few adjustments to your popup-panel classes that display the pointer.  This will keep the pointer centered on the button and will keep the panel right justified like you requested in the example.

```
#btn-wrap {
    /* you could position it absolute, the popup will follow */
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    /* try any of these alternatives to float:right
    margin-left:100px;
    float:left;
    */

    /*Set the input/button container dimensions = button size*/
    width: 65px;
    height: 20px;
}

.sf-popup-panel.popup.open:before {
    ........
    ....
    right: 13px; /* set right instead of left */
    left: auto;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.sf-popup-panel.open:after {
    ........
    ....
    right: 13px; /* set right instead of left */
    left: auto;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Coincidently, I ended up with the same solution since I posted :) Good I did not have to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing as follows :-

```
.sf-popup-panel.popup {
        top: auto;
        right: -70px;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
.sf-popup-panel.popup.open:before,.sf-popup-panel.open:after  {
  right: 40px;
}
```

**Don't forget to remove `left:50%`.**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ru5aX/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.sf-popup-panel {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}




.sf-popup-panel.popup.open:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border: 14px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    top: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: 80%;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.sf-popup-panel.open:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    top: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: 80%;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the button is left aligned with parent? I cannot make assumptions about the alignment of the button with respect to it's parent. The popup has to appear where ever the button is.